# OSError: [WinError 10057]

Tags: python, sockets

```py
import socket
import threading
host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 36250

def RetrFile(sock):
  from account import posts
  filename = 'posts.txt'
  for item in posts(filename):
    sock.send(item)
  sock.send("DONE".encode())

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
  h_name = socket.gethostname()
  IP_address = socket.gethostbyname(h_name)
  s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
  s.bind((IP_address,port))
  print("Server started")
  print("IP address:", IP_address)

  while True:
    print("Waiting for clients...")
    s.listen()
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Client connected, IP: " + str(addr))
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data == "POSTS".encode():
      t = threading.Thread(target=RetrFile, args=(c))
      t.start()
  s.close()
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\####\Downloads\Social-media-server (1)\main.py", line 26, in <module>
    data = s.recv(1024)
OSError: [WinError 10057] En begäran att skicka eller ta emot data tilläts inte eftersom socketen inte är ansluten och (när du skickar på en datagramsocket med hjälp av ett sendto-anrop) ingen adress angavs
```

Translated:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\####\Downloads\Social-media-server (1)\main.py", line 26, in <module>
    data = s.recv(1024)
OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was not allowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was specified
```

I have tried `sendall` but it did not change a thing, what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```py
data = s.recv(1024)
```

It should be `c.recv` to read from the accepted client socket, not `s.recv` to read from the listening socket.

Comment: Thank you! Just a final question, does it work the same way with `send`?